# Error when connecting to AWS from check_nrpe

Tags: amazon-web-services, nagios

When I'm trying to connect from check_nrpe to AWS instance of a Windows server, I'm getting the following error:

```
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not connect to 35.154.162.178. Check system logs on 35.154.162.178 a,port 5666 open on both machine
```

Comment: I've edited your question to be a bit more readable but you need to provide more details to this problem if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the port 5666/tcp is closed to the server..

could you try

```
nmap -p 5666 [target ip]
```